# How to add days to a TIMESTAMP?

Tags: datetime, abap

How can I add 1 day to a time of type `TIMESTAMP` and have the month/year roll over correctly?

For example:

```
data lv_time type TIMESTAMP value '20180228000000'.
data(lv_new_time) = lv_time + 1. " should be '20180301000000', but instead is '20180228000001'
data(lv_new_time2) = lv_time + 1000000. " should be '20180301000000', but instead is '20180229000000'
```

Comment: In SAP the TIMESTAMP type is simply a floating point type therefore the results you get are correct. However there is a way to do it in a neat way. I remember I did it some time ago but I have to browse through my resources. Will let you know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work for you. The function module that should be available in your system is `TIMESTAMP_DURATION_ADD`.

```
REPORT zzz.

DATA lv_time TYPE timestamp VALUE '20180228000000'.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA timestamp_out TYPE timestamp.

  CALL FUNCTION 'TIMESTAMP_DURATION_ADD'
    EXPORTING
      timestamp_in    = lv_time
      timezone        = 'UTC'
      duration        = 1
      unit            = 'TAG' " day (in German)
    IMPORTING
      timestamp_out   = timestamp_out
    EXCEPTIONS
      timestamp_error = 1
      OTHERS          = 2.

  ASSERT sy-subrc = 0.

  WRITE timestamp_out.
```

Answer (score 7):

After looking at [Jagger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4411/jagger)'s answer, I looked under the hood of the `TIMESTAMP_DURATION_ADD` function and discovered some ABAP syntax that does the job without needing a function call at all.

```
constants: lc_time_zone type timezone value 'UTC'.
data lv_timestamp_before type timestamp value '20180228001234'.
data lv_timestamp_after type timestamp.
data lv_date like sy-datum.
data lv_time like sy-uzeit.

convert time stamp lv_timestamp_before time zone lc_time_zone
    into date lv_date time lv_time.
lv_date = lv_date + 1.
convert date lv_date time lv_time
    into time stamp lv_timestamp_after time zone lc_time_zone.
```

Comment: I still think calling a function module is a better idea. :)

Comment: @Jagger, how come? :)  Personally, I like the idea of using basic ABAP syntax. It takes only 3 lines of code and is more system-independent.

Comment: General rule of thumb : SAP says to not use "unreleased" function modules (i.e. one day, SAP could remove it without warning or mark it obsolete). CONVERT is released and documented. And CONVERT is much faster.

Comment: @SandraRossi On the other hand, the general rule of thumb has that you should not duplicate the code. :)

Comment: @Jagger That's not a "duplicate" because it's only 3 ABAP statements - could even simplify it to remove the 2 CONVERT, and do only assignments, no need to be inspired by some SAP code :) `data(tstmp) = value tzntimestp( lv_timestamp ). ADD 1 TO tstmp(8). lv_timestamp = tstmp.` but well, I don't like it a lot, so no solution is perfect ! (essentially because SAP does not provide a kernel-based date/time library)

Answer (score 7):

If you're not into resurrecting old procedural programming, you could use the class `CL_ABAP_TSTMP` as described in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abencl_abap_tstmp.htm).

```
DATA some_timestamp TYPE timestamp VALUE '20180228000000'.
DATA(new_timestamp) = cl_abap_tstmp=>add(
    tstmp = some_timestamp
    secs  = ( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  )
).
```

(Too bad `CL_ABAP_TSTMP=>SECSOFDAY` is private... But hey, at least that makes you think about what to do with leap years...)

Comment: Can you please give a working code example for our readers? :)

Comment: Neat. Suites exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use FM IAM_TIMESTAMP_CALC to add one day to a timestamp, the result will be 20180301000000:

```
  DATA lv_time TYPE timestamp VALUE '20180228000000'.

  CALL FUNCTION 'IAM_TIMESTAMP_CALC'
    EXPORTING
      iv_refdate = lv_time
*     IV_XBACKWARD       =
      iv_days    = '1'
*     IV_HOURS   = '0'
*     IV_MINUTES = '0'
*     IV_SECONDS = '0'
    IMPORTING
      ev_date    = lv_time.
```

Comment: Dumps with the error message `Function module "IAM_TIMESTAMP_CALC" not found`

Comment: For Pete's Sake, which SAP version are you running? that FM exists since 2005 (although is not released)

Comment: The function module `IAM_TIMESTAMP_CALC` doesn't exist on the S/4HANA Infinity System (software component `S4CORE`), nor on the Suite on HANA Infinity System (software component `SAP_APPL`). Hence, it's definitely not a standard function.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if it will work, but maybe it's worth the try.

Extract the date of the timestamp, add one day to the date, and just create a new timestamp with the new date and the rest of the timestamp.

Something like

```
data: stamp type timestamp value '20180301000000000',
      stamp_date type dats,
      new_stamp type timestamp.
stamp_date = stamp(8). "if it doesn't work, just look for a FM
add 1 to stamp_date.
new_stamp = stamp_date && stamp+8.
```

I'm not sure if it will work "as is", but I'm pretty sure you can find a way to make it work from there... while we both wait for the proper answer ;)

Comment: The above code will dump at `stamp_date = stamp(8)` with the message `Overflow during an arithmetic operation (type P)`. I know it's weird, since the `DATETIME` is really a string one would expect string manipulation functions to work on it. What Function Module would you recommend? Can you give an example of using it in this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: I do not provide full working code, just hints. Check Joszef answer, it works.

Comment: This is not even a sensible approach. Please remove this "answer" and stop leading other people in search of answers up the garden path.

Comment: Up to now, the most voted answer uses that non-sensible approach, just with a proper working code snippet.
Maybe you are right about my answer, but as I'm pretty new here, and I'm not sure about it, feel free to flag it and let the mods delete it if proceed. I'll not complaint about it.
I will just let people to sink my answer by raising the more appropiate ones, if you don't care.